# How to get the value from string in Sql Server,

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to get the value from string in Sql Server,

Example : i have one column data like "Delhi-123456-PO-2356". i want to get the only 123456 (after first -) from this string using Sql server.

Without using Stored procedure!!

Comment: Have you considered doing that extraction of part of your data with whatever high level language you are using for your application.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [parsename()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function :

```
select *, parsename(replace(col, '-', '.'), 3) as newcol
from table t;
```

Comment: Thanks for idea. Cool. I think, Its best answer and recommend use this.
Here is real example of usage: https://pastebin.com/FZ3u6nHs

Comment: Keep in mind that this will work if you have 3 hyphens (4 strings concatenated) only.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUBSTR("Delhi-123456-PO-2356",7,6) AS answer
```

Explaination: function SUBSTR(data,startIndex,length)

startIndex calculated from 0

Comment: may delhi will be long string in future.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this primitive solution:

```
declare @str nvarchar(256) = N'Delhi-123456-PO-2356';

select left(
     substring(@str, charindex('-', @str) + 1, len(@str) - charindex('-', @str))
    ,charindex('-', substring(@str, charindex('-', @str) + 1, len(@str) - charindex('-', @str))) - 1
);
```

Or more advanced:

```
declare @str nvarchar(256) = N'Delhi-123456-PO-2356';

;with [data] as (
    select [str] =  substring(@str, charindex('-', @str) + 1, len(@str) - charindex('-', @str))
)
select left(
     [str]
    ,charindex('-', [str]) - 1
) from [data];
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get the correct value no matter the number of hyphens.

```
DECLARE @teststring varchar(100) = 'Delhi-123456-PO-2356'

SELECT LEFT(SUBSTRING(@teststring, CHARINDEX('-', @teststring) + 1, LEN(@teststring)), 
            CHARINDEX( '-', SUBSTRING(@teststring
                                    , CHARINDEX('-', @teststring) + 1
                                    , LEN(@teststring))) - 1)
```

Returns

```
123456
```

Best practice, would save each of the 4 parts into 4 separate columns.  Saving multiple values into a single string is a violation of [First Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form).